# C# Mongo Client stuck forever with no primary after failover

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-atlas

C# `MongoDb.Driver` v2.11.4

After a failover we're seeing some servers get stuck forever without a primary and are therefore unable to complete any write operations. There's 10 servers in the farm - most of them just recover as expected - they find the newly elected primary and start using that however, sometimes a server gets stuck in a state where it has no primary and it never gets updated with the new one.

Client view of cluster state is

```
{ 
    ClusterId : "1", 
    ConnectionMode : "ReplicaSet", 
    Type : "ReplicaSet", 
    State : "Connected", 
    Servers : [
        { 
            ServerId: "{ ClusterId : 1, EndPoint : "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" }", 
            EndPoint: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", 
            ReasonChanged: "Heartbeat", 
            State: "Connected", 
            ServerVersion: 4.0.24, 
            TopologyVersion: , 
            Type: "ReplicaSetSecondary", 
            Tags: "{ nodeType : ELECTABLE, region : EU_WEST_1, workloadType : OPERATIONAL, provider : AWS }", 
            WireVersionRange: "[0, 7]", 
            LastHeartbeatTimestamp: "2021-05-02T08:07:30.2522182Z", 
            LastUpdateTimestamp: "2021-05-02T08:07:30.2522183Z" 
        }, 
        { 
            ServerId: "{ ClusterId : 1, EndPoint : "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" }", 
            EndPoint: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", 
            ReasonChanged: "InvalidatedBecause:NoLongerPrimary", 
            State: "Disconnected", 
            ServerVersion: , 
            TopologyVersion: , 
            Type: "Unknown", 
            LastHeartbeatTimestamp: null, 
            LastUpdateTimestamp: "2021-05-02T08:07:40.2501137Z" 
        }, 
        { 
            ServerId: "{ ClusterId : 1, EndPoint : "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" }", 
            EndPoint: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", 
            ReasonChanged: "Heartbeat", 
            State: "Connected", 
            ServerVersion: 4.0.24, 
            TopologyVersion: , 
            Type: "ReplicaSetSecondary", 
            Tags: "{ region : EU_WEST_1, workloadType : OPERATIONAL, provider : AWS, nodeType : ELECTABLE }", 
            WireVersionRange: "[0, 7]", 
            LastHeartbeatTimestamp: "2021-05-02T08:07:39.9702270Z", 
            LastUpdateTimestamp: "2021-05-02T08:07:39.9702272Z" 
        }, 
        { 
            ServerId: "{ ClusterId : 1, EndPoint : "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" }", 
            EndPoint: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", 
            ReasonChanged: "Heartbeat", 
            State: "Connected", 
            ServerVersion: 4.0.24, 
            TopologyVersion: , 
            Type: "ReplicaSetSecondary", 
            Tags: "{ region : US_WEST_2, nodeType : READ_ONLY, provider : AWS, workloadType : OPERATIONAL }", 
            WireVersionRange: "[0, 7]", 
            LastHeartbeatTimestamp: "2021-05-02T08:07:40.1347853Z", 
            LastUpdateTimestamp: "2021-05-02T08:07:40.1347855Z" 
        }, 
        { 
            ServerId: "{ ClusterId : 1, EndPoint : "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" }", 
            EndPoint: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", 
            ReasonChanged: "Heartbeat", 
            State: "Connected", 
            ServerVersion: 4.0.24, 
            TopologyVersion: , 
            Type: "ReplicaSetSecondary", 
            Tags: "{ region : US_EAST_1, workloadType : OPERATIONAL, provider : AWS, nodeType : READ_ONLY }", 
            WireVersionRange: "[0, 7]", 
            LastHeartbeatTimestamp: "2021-05-02T08:07:40.2418292Z", 
            LastUpdateTimestamp: "2021-05-02T08:07:40.2418294Z" 
        }, 
        { 
            ServerId: "{ ClusterId : 1, EndPoint : "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" }", 
            EndPoint: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", 
            ReasonChanged: "Heartbeat", 
            State: "Connected", 
            ServerVersion: 4.0.24, 
            TopologyVersion: , 
            Type: "ReplicaSetGhost", 
            WireVersionRange: "[0, 7]", 
            LastHeartbeatTimestamp: "2021-05-02T08:07:32.0525585Z", 
            LastUpdateTimestamp: "2021-05-02T08:07:32.0525586Z" 
        }
    ] 
}
```

I have a feeling that the election is taking too long for some servers and they just give up checking for the new primary??  Are there any setting to control how many times or how frequently the driver checks for a new primary?

We're using `MongoClient` as a singleton as recommended.

We've added code to handle the `TimeoutException`s that are inevitably thrown by parsing the state and re-creating the `MongoClient` after x number of failures but this feels like a hack because the state is the same as it should be during a failover but it just doesn't recover and x number of failures is a completely arbitrary number - no amount of retries will ever work.

Isn't the driver supposed to handle this?

It's odd as it doesn't affect all servers in the farm which have exactly the same code, hardware and are connecting to the same cluster.

Is there a recommended way to identify when the driver gets stuck like this and then recover 'properly'?

We will also bump to the latest version of the driver but that doesn't really seem like an actual 'solution' unless someone is able to point me to a known bug/fix??

Thanks in advance

Comment: I would recommend updating up to the latest 2.12.x driver (I know that a similar issue was fixed in 2.11.6), if it won't help, it's better to create a jira ticket in mongo csharp project

Comment: Which node was elected primary?  That output shows 6 servers, one is disconnected, and 2 haven't been heard from in 8-9 seconds.

Comment: @dododo We have updated the driver and will continue to monitor. Thanks for your input.

Comment: @Joe The disconnected server is the old primary.  The new primary is the 1st server in the array.  I assume the other serves had not been heard from as I expect they had just gone through the same upgrade process (this failover was caused by an automated minor version update from Mongo Atlas)